# Match Array values and merge if the values matches in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array i want to match a key of first array with another array and if the values of both key matches then add the value of second array to array 1

Array 1

```
[{"currency":1,"amount":23},{"currency":1,"amount":30},{"currency":2,"amount":40},]
```

Array 2

```
[{"currency_id": 1,"currency_symbol":$},{"currency_id":2,"currency_symbol":€}]
```

Desired output is:

```
[{"currency":$,"amount":23},{"currency":$,"amount":30},{"currency":€,"amount":40}]
```

The Code i am using is:

```
foreach($a1 as $key) {
            foreach($a2 as $cKey){
                if($a1['currency']==$a2['currency_id']){
                    $a1['currency_symbol'] = $a2['currency_symbol'];
                    echo $a1['currency_symbol'];
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: what have you implemented so far to achieve desired output?

Comment: i tried with foreach loop but i dont know to match key values with other array,

Comment: post your code.

Comment: check my Edit. I am able to get the currency in forerach loop. But i am not able to access `$a1['currency_symbol']` out side the loop

Comment: your code is working.. look into my answer once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($arr1 as $k=>$key) {
    foreach($arr2 as $cKey){
        if($key['currency']==$cKey['currency_id']){
            $arr3[$k]['currency'] = $cKey['currency_symbol'];
            $arr3[$k]['amount'] = $key['amount'];
        }
    }
}
var_export($arr3);
```

You only need to assign variable and print outside loop.